# Checking NaN value in r

Tags: r

I have a code which generate `NaN` values:

```
j<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
m=acf(j,lag.max=32,ylim=c(-1,1),plot=FALSE)
```

I want to check if the values are `Nan` :

```
is.nan(m[1])
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Error in is.nan(m[1]) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

what shoul I do to solve this problem? (checking Nan valus)

Comment: I think you want to use `[[` instead of a simple `[` (this is equivalent to `is.nan(m$acf)`, see `str(m)`), try `is.nan(m[[1]])` or even shorter `any(is.nan(m[[1]]))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`acf` returns a named list. If you want to find `NaN` values in the acf estimates, use

```
is.nan(m$acf)
```

Comment: ...or `is.nan(m[["acf"]])`.